# Flex grid not resizing for @media queries

Tags: css, flexbox

I cannot figure out why my 4 column (flexbox) grid doesn't resize when using @media queries. I have my code here: https://jsfiddle.net/mrknz4a3/

```
.flexgrid-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 1% 0;
    margin: 2% 0 0;
}

.row {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

.col_3 {
    width: 23%;
    margin: 0 2.7% 2.5% 0;
    float: left;
    word-break: break-word;
    background: pink;
}
```

To change the layout I've been using the following code but the layout stays exactly the same. I want a 2 column layout for tablets/iPad and 1 column for smartphones:

```
/* iPad portrait */
@media  screen and (min-width: 641px) and (max-width: 959px) {
  .col_3 { width: 48.5%; }
}

/* Smartphones */
@media  screen and (max-width : 480px), /* Portrait */
            screen and (max-width : 640px) /* Landscape */ {

  .col_3 { width: 100%; margin-right:0; }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider adding `flex-wrap: wrap` to your flex container (`.row`). The default setting for a flex container is `flex-wrap: nowrap` and all flex items will stay on the same line.

> [**5.2. Flex Line Wrapping: the `flex-wrap`
>   property**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-wrap-property)
>
> The `flex-wrap` property controls whether the flex container is
>   single-line or multi-line, and the direction of the cross-axis, which
>   determines the direction new lines are stacked in.
>
> ***nowrap*** (initial value)
>
> The flex container is single-line.
>
> ***wrap***
>
> The flex container is multi-line.
>
> *<sub>source:
>   https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-wrap-property</sub>*

---

Separately, you are using `float` and `clear` properties in your flex container. Note that these properties are ignored and can be safely removed.

> [**3. Flex Containers: the `flex` and `inline-flex` display
>   values**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers)
>
> A flex container establishes a new ***flex formatting context*** for
>   its contents. This is the same as establishing a block formatting
>   context, except that flex layout is used instead of block layout:
>   *floats do not intrude into the flex container*, and the flex
>   container’s margins do not collapse with the margins of its contents.
>
> - `float` and `clear` have no effect on a flex item, and do not take it out-of-flow.
>
> *<sub>source:
>   https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers</sub>*

Comment: Perfect. I thought it would be a simple one liner I was missing. There are so many little tweaks for flex box and I'm just not up to speed with them yet. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Pleas add the flex-wrap property to the `.row` class.

```
.row {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -moz-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap:wrap;
        clear: both;
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
    }
```

Please see [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) the complete guidelines of flex boxes .