# css grid media query

Tags: css, media-queries, css-grid

First up not my code, following a tutorial folks, but have an issue with the media query. Using Chrome browser

Large screen css, which is working fine

```
/* Navigation */
.main-nav ul {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}
```

Mediq query

```
/* Media Queries */
@media (max-width: 700px) {
    .top-container {
        grid-template-areas: 
            'showcase showcase'
            'top-box-a top-box-b';
    }

    .showcase h1 {
        font-size: 2.5rem;
    }

    .main-nav ul {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
}
```

The media query works except for the main-nav which is still showing the four ul items horizontally, rather than single options horizontally.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flex grid not resizing for @media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35699289/flex-grid-not-resizing-for-media-queries)

Answer (score 0):

The way your code currently sits, it all seems to be working as I understand your issue. I've created a JSFiddle to recreate what you're working on. Could you modify it and show us your code in relation to the issue?

My only other suggestion without seeing your DOM is to try using `grid-template-rows` as well, to tell it exactly how many rows it has to fill (although you shouldn't need this):

```
@media (max-width: 700px){
    .main-nav ul {
        grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fqx7hayb/11/